# How to insert the value of multiple drop-down menus in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page to insert meeting details, one of the sections of this insert form is selecting the attendance from existing list of members in db. My question is: How to insert many drop-down menus (max number of menus is equal to the total number of members) in mysql db. This way works great in other scenario that I have done the only difference that it was an input type of text instead of select menu **So What did I miss here ?**

Bellow all the code:

[addMeeting.php](http://www.4shared.com/file/Zw8sqNJIba/addMeeting.html)

[DB](http://www.4shared.com/office/nEo9IloNce/db_online.html)

Comment: I don't get errors, its just dose not insert :(

Comment: remove 0 from the  `name="attendace[0]"` like `attendance[]`

Comment: @RaheelKhan I did it but nothing inserted :"(

Comment: From what I can see there is no form, so nothing gets posted, and it's very unclear how it's supposed to fit together. Nothing seems to have any connection to anything else. I would suggest starting from scratch, (re-)learning HTML forms and how to use them with PHP.

Comment: @sxefloden Dear, not adding the whole code doesn't mean I should back to school and re-learn, I updated my question hopping it's more clear now :)

Comment: No it doesn't, but from what was available, neither the HTML nor the backend made much sense. There was no form tag <nd $Attendance wasn't set anywhere, for instance. It seems that updating your question gave results though, which is nice.

Comment: @sxefloden I truly get what you mean now, thank you for that lesson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my scenario to this: instead of having many drop down lists I created one select of multiple values and I could manage getting an array of the user selected values and insert them successfully ^^

So Don't complicate your code > Hard lesson :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

If  I understand:

You wont to write how many attendance there are for a specific meeting right ?

if this is your case **you should already know your "meetingID".**

```
// for example ...
$meetingID = $_POST['meetingid']; 
$reruslt =& mysql_query('INSERT INTO meetingattendance (meetingID, attendance) VALUES ('.$meetingID.', "'.$new_attendence.'")', $conn);
if(!$reruslt) die( 'mySQL err. '.mysql_errno($conn).': '.mysql_error($conn) );
```

LAST_INSERT_ID() only return the last inserted auto increment key, in this case "boardmeetings.meetingID".

CONSTRAIN FOREIGN KEY make sure that you cannot insert a meetingID in "meetingattendance" that does not exists in "boardmeetings".

You should use LAST_INSERT_ID() **only directly after an insert** in "boardmeetings".

**MYSQL**:

```
INSERT INTO `boardmeetings`(`meetingID`) VALUES ('');
@lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO meetingattendance (meetingID, attendance) VALUES (@lastID, 'new_attendence');
```

Or in **PHP**

```
$reruslt =& mysql_query('INSERT INTO boardmeetings (meetingID) VALUES ('')', $con);
$lastID = mysql_insert_id($conn);
$reruslt2 =& mysql_query('INSERT INTO meetingattendance (meetingID, attendance) VALUES ('.$lastID.', "'.$new_attendence.'")', $conn);
if(!$reruslt2) die( 'mySQL err. '.mysql_errno($conn).': '.mysql_error($conn) );
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate ? I manage listing all existing members but I could not manage inserting the selected ones ?

Comment: @frderico Btw my scenario is to select the attendance of the meeting among stored existing members only

Comment: I mean if the values of the selection are the "attendance" you get from DB. you will re-insert the same values only with another id.....

Comment: by the way, is the "meetingID" an auto increment.... or is a reference to another table ?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is only usable on auto increment .... maybe can you provide some more detail on the table meetingattendance.

Comment: I added the DB info .. Waiting for your feedback :")

Comment: No not at all, I am truly sorry for making it hard to get a help. Anyway I updated my question check it plz :)

Answer (score 2):

can you show me the code where you are inserting a new meeting in `boardmeetings`. I believe you are doing it just before `if (isset ($_POST['attendence'])&& $_POST['attendence']!='none')`

is this you full addMeeting.php code?

```
<?php
$dbhost="XXX";
$dbuser="XXX";
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, "XXX");
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$query = "SELECT * FROM `boardteam` ORDER BY fName ASC";
mysql_select_db('dahBoard');
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
{
   while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
     $Attendence .= "<option value=".$db_field['nationalID'].">".$db_field['titleName']."."." ".$db_field['fName']." ".$db_field['sName']." ".$db_field['lName']."</option>";
     }
 }

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
   if (isset ($_POST['attendence'])&& $_POST['attendence']!='none') {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['attendence']); $i++) {
    $new_attendence = $_POST['attendence'][$i];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `meetingattendance`(`meetingID`, `attendance`) 
              VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$new_attendence')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Not not the full I thought if I did it will be much harder but now I believe its a way much easier :D

Comment: I will plz wait it 364 line :")

Comment: Updated my question, Please help :")