# How to update MySQL db from two associative array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I received two associative array and I want to update it's values in mysql db. So, I did this:

```
// for all other contacts
if(isset($_POST['otherAddress']) || isset($_POST['otherComments']))
{
    $otherAddress = $_POST['otherAddress'];
    $otherComments = $_POST['otherComments'];

    foreach (array_keys($otherAddress + $otherComments) as $key) 
    {
        $query = "UPDATE `boardcontacts` SET
        `address`='$otherAddress[$key]',`comments`='$otherComments[$key]'
        WHERE `memberID` = '$nID' AND `addressType`='other'";

        mysql_query($query);
    } // for end
} // if end
```

**Problem is:** It duplicate all updated rows with the last index of each array.
Any help ?

Comment: can you please show your  $otherAddress and  $otherComments array . It will help us to resolve your problem.

Comment: what is $nID here. can you please specify me.

Comment: @NavjotSingh its the national ID the board members

Comment: @Asmaa your entire query emphasize on $nID. But in your query $nID not appear inside the loop. If it vary update unique row.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh ex: $otherAddress={@abc,@dfg}  $otherAddress={twitter,instegram}

Comment: this is really, but really not safe method you do... how can you call yourself as programmer??!

Comment: $otherComments={twitter,instegram} **

Comment: @Legionar Can you please specify my mistake ? Can you improve my programming skills without Insulting me ?

Comment: @AsmaaAlharbi here you are - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious are you updating the value of `$nID`??
Because if the `foreach` executes without updating `$nID` the query will update the values in the same row every time because the `where` condition is same every time.

Comment: You are write this is the issue, Now my question is how to solve it ?

Comment: That depends on your logic... from where you want to get the memberID?

Comment: I guess the fastest way is to add a column "contactID" as an auto increment that differentiate each row in boardContact table and pass it along with the $nID will solve the problem ^^

Comment: Yes you are correct. But if you clearly post your exact array format of $otherAddress and $otherComments, then your above code will be also modified for desired result.

Comment: Thank You so much your answer is accepted and if you can plz help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924784/how-to-insert-the-value-of-multiple-drop-down-menus-in-php#_=_)